# Chrome 84 начали пропадать SVG иконки

Tags: html, google-chrome

После обновления Chrome до 84.0.4147.89 на сайтах начали пропадать svg-иконки размеченные с помощью тега use. Что более удивительно - не все и после обновления они возвращаются.

```
<svg><use xlink:href="sprite.svg#pencil"></use></svg>
```

Есть какая-нибудь информация по этой проблеме?

Comment: Все точно также, сам ищу решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое решение для меня стало подключение SVG-спрайтов в тело документа.

Было

```
<svg><use xlink:href="sprite.svg#pencil"></use></svg>
```

Стало

```
<svg><use xlink:href="#pencil"></use></svg>
<svg><use xlink:href="#delete"></use></svg>
<div style="display:none">
    <svg>
        <symbol id="pencil">...</symbol>
        <symbol id="delete">...</symbol>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Минусы:

1. Увеличение DOM,
2. SVG-спрайт больше не кешируется и загружается при каждой загрузке страницы,
3. Нужно контролировать id. Потому что если на странице появится второй элемент с одинаковым id, может что-то сломаться в JS или не будет работать иконка.

Плюсы:

1. Не создает лишних запросов,
2. Фиксит проблему 84 хрома.